# Function to calculate how often users are pressing a button

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have got a function. Below is a prototype

```
void onNewButtonPress(int64_t nanoseconds_timestamp, int32_t user_id);
```

A bit of destription. This function will be called each time a user with a user_id is pressing the button. Where nanoseconds_timestamp parameter is the time in nanoseconds since the epoch

This function will need to get the rate of user button presses, basically how many times per second a user pressed a button.

How can I calculate the rate for each user, store it and update it periodically? Is it possible to do it using just above function or I will have to create another function which will be called periodically and will calculate the rates.

How do I deal with users which started pressing button close to the end of the period. Do I need to average it?

I will be very interested to hear your opinions based on your experience.

Comment: What does the `nanoseconds` parameter represent? The duration of time the button was held down? How is the function supposed to calculate how often per-second a user presses the button? Just by checking system time when the call is made?

Comment: As said by @scohe001, it highly depends on what `nanoseconds` means and how do you plan to store and use the rate you want to calculate, since I see no structure capable of holding these data.

Comment: Sorry guys. I forgot to mention it. nanoseconds is time in nanoseconds since an epoch. I will edit the question

Comment: As an aside, this shows that your function parameter name is not descriptive enough. Never use just units, unless the function name itself contains enough information to determine the context of the value.

Comment: Is the rate defined over the entire test period, or over some fixed window of time?  If it’s over the whole period, you can just divide the number of clicks by the duration of the test; otoh if you want eg “the average rate over the last 5 seconds”, you’ll need to keep a list of click-timestamps for each user So that you can count how many times he clicked over the last 5 seconds, then divide by 5.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner. Thank you, guys for your responses. I really appreciate your help. I was thinking to count number of clicks by the period. Tes will run multiple number of predefined periods lets say 5 second periods. What would be the best way to calculate the average across multiple periods. Say for example we had 20 periods. For every period rate was different. How would you calculate the average. I can think of moving average for example which will require a bit of rate history from the past periods. Can you think of anything else

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner. And something else. What would be the best way. Do not save the rate for the first incomplete period. For example if a user clicked at the middle of the current time window do we still save the rate eventhough it was not calculated over the full time window.

Comment: Sounds like maybe for each user you’d want to save the time stamp of the first click, the time stamp of the last click, and the number of clicks; then at the end you could subtract the first-click-time stamp from the last-click-time stamp and divide the click-count by that.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner With the average is easy and I agree with your idea. What if I want to get the maximum click rate seen over the whole set of periods? I have noticed that the max click rate will be at the first incomplete period and all the other rates will be less than that. Do I need to count the rate at the first incomplete period. I assume not.

Comment: @slaventos a lot depends on what you mean by 'maximum click rate'.  One way to do it would be to record timestamps of all clicks (which you'll probably want to do anyway) and then iterate over the sequence of timestamps for each user and find the smallest time-delta between one timestamp and the next one; if two clicks is enough to establish a "click rate", then you can take the reciprocal of that time-delta (in seconds) and you have your maximum-click-rate-in-clicks-per-second.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Why do I need to record timestamps of all clicks if I can just save the last time stamp and update on every click and calculate the rate on every click event and keep only the maximum rate. Basically every entry for a user will have a lastTs and maxRate data members which will be updated on every click. I was thinking to update these 2 data members every periodic event for example every 5 seconds but not to count the first incomplete period. Anyways, thank you for your thoughts

Comment: @slaventos it depends on how you want to process the data and what statistics you hope to derive from the data.  Some statistics require looking at all the timestamps at once, others require only looking at the latest timestamp and the previous timestamp.  Do what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

Have a global/member variable that stores the users timestamps

```
std::map<int32_t, int64_t> lastClick;
```

Then calculate the difference and invert it to get the rate:

```cpp
   void onNewButtonPress(int64_t nanoseconds_timestamp, int32_t user_id) {
      if (auto last = lastClick[user_id]) {
         auto rate = 1000000000 / (nanoseconds_timestamp - last);
         // Use the rate for something
         lastClick[user_id] = nanoseconds_timestamp;
      }
   }
```

Comment: What if I want to count number of presses per some period. The rate should be reported as presses/second. User will not press button periodically. For example it may press 1000 of times withing the first 1000 nanoseconds and then it will not press until the next second. The events may be spread not evenly through time. Thank you, guys for your ideas, anyway.

Comment: @drescherjm: `std::map<int64_t>` is not valid C++. More appropriate would be `std::map<int32_t, int64_t>`.

Comment: @slaventos To turn the timestamps into what you want requires some statistical analysis, which you can study about, but this is the data storage implementation you'll need to get started. I'm not convinced by Laserskold's attempt at the statistical part though.

Comment: Yes i wrote it in the webbrowser so  i might had missed some details. And the first solution obviously does not calculate the rate between two fixed timepoints, but rather between two clicks. I'm a bit surprised nobody else has suggested a solution to the full problem yet.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I dont want to compicate things too much hence I am not looking into application of statistical analysis to this particular problem. @Laserskold, thank you for your code example but I havent found the right solution yet.