# Reporting when user exceeded the limit for button clicks

Tags: c++, c++17

I got a function which which was mentioned in on of my previous questions:
[Function to calculate how often users are pressing a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836214/function-to-calculate-how-often-users-are-pressing-a-button)

```
void onNewButtonPress(int64_t nanoseconds_timestamp, int32_t user_id);
```

This function will be called each time a user with a user_id is clicking the button.
Where nanoseconds_timestamp parameter is the time in nanoseconds since the epoch.

My task is to do the rate limit checks for each user. Every user has its own click rate limit.
Rate limit for every user can be retrieved using the following function:

```
const struct rate_limit* getLimit(uint32_t userId);
```

getlimit will return a pointer to a struct Rate_limit

```
struct rate_limit
{
    uint32_t max;
    uint32_t milliseconds;
};
```

Where max is the maximum number of clicks a user can make within the interval of milliseconds value. For example if max = 400 and milliseconds = 200, then a user can only make 400 clicks within 200 ms interval.

When a user breaches the limit the function should report it using report function with a prototype as follows.

```
void report(uint32_t user_id);
```

How would you, folks, detect when user breaches its limit. Below is my solution with comments. I still believe that there may be much smarter and better solution and would like to hear your opinions.

My implementation details are as follows

I created a structure which will contain information about every user history.

```
struct UserTrackingInfo
{
    /* Limit which is returned when a user clicks for the first time */
    const rate_limit* limit;

    /* Variable which will get incremented each time a user is making a click */
    uint32_t breachCount{0};

    /* Timestamp in nanoseconds of when breachPeriod started. Whenever a user clicks for the first time
     * this timestamp will be initialized
     * Time will be sliced in breach periods whose duration is equal to the max of the rate_limit */
    uint64_t breachPeriodStartTs{0};
};
```

I created a map where key is the user_id and value is UserTrackingInfo

```
std::map<int32_t, struct UserTrackingInfo > tInfo;
```

This is my proposed implementation of the function onNewButtonPress.

```
void onNewButtonPress(uint64_t& nanoseconds_timestamp, int32_t user_id)
{
    auto &tref = tInfo[user_id];


    if (tref.breachPeriodStartTs == 0){
        /* if a user hasnt clicked before, get the limit for the user and initialize a breach period start time stamp */
        tref.limit = getLimit(user_id);
        tref.breachPeriodStartTs = nanoseconds_timestamp;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Increment how many times used clicked a button */
        tref.breachCount++;

        /* Get number of ns passed since the time when last period started */
        int64_t passed = nanoseconds_timestamp - tref.breachPeriodStartTs;

        /* If we reached a limit, report it */
        if (passed < (tref.limit->milliseconds * 1000)){
            if (tref.breachCount > tref.limit->max){
                report(user_id);
            }
            /* we dont start a new period yet */
        }
        else{
            /* If the limit hasnt been reached yet */
            /* User may have pressed after the end of the breach period. Or he didnt make any clicks for the duration of a couple of breach periods */

            /* Find number of breach measure periods that may have been missed */
            uint64_t num_periods = passed / (tref.limit->milliseconds * 1000);

            /* Get duration of the passed periods in nanoseconds */
            uint64_t num_periods_ns = num_periods * (tref.limit->milliseconds * 1000);

            /* Set the the start time of the current breach measure period */
            /* and reset breachCount */
            tref.breachPeriodStartTs = tref.breachPeriodStartTs + num_periods_ns;
            tref.breachCount = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code work? You didn't say. Questions about how to improve working code are better placed on the Code Review Stack Exchange instead. Otherwise, please explain the problem.

Comment: Yes, the concept that I am trying to demonstrate works, however I am thinking of any other better way to do it, because I got a couple of tracking related variables per each user which may or may not be avoided. And I am not sure whether the tracking algorithm is correct. May be I have missed couple of corner cases. Just wanted to hear other opinions

Comment: I would store `rate_limit` not as `x` clicks per `y` milliseconds, but just as one number - `x` clicks per second. It would be much easier from there on

Answer (score 0):

I would count how many clicks user does per astronomical second (so no storing and checking of beginning of your clicking period). The advantage is simplicity, but disadvantage is that if user starts clicking in the end of a second, then he has say 1000 clicks for the remaining of this second plus 1000 clicks for the next second (i.e. he can do for example 2000 clicks per 1.1 second, but it only works for the first second, the next seconds will be limited properly). So:

- Record click counts in `std::map`, it would be O(logN) to update, but could be O(1) with `std::unordered_map` (requires hashing implementation) or `std::vector` (requires users ids to be contiguous, but simple to implement)
- Record which users were active in last second in `std::set` (O(logN) insert and delete) or `std::unordered_set` (O(1) insert and delete)
- Record a nanosecond of a beginning of the next second from current

In your click handler you first check if a new second started (it's easy, check if your timestamp is after the timestamp of the next second). If so, then reset counts of all active users (this active users tracking is for not wasting time iterating the whole `std::map`). Then clear active users.

Next handle the actual click. Get a record from the map and update count, check if limit is exceeded and do the reporting if it is.

Note that handling the next second beginning is a somewhat heavy operation, and user click would not be processed until the next second is handled (might lead to a delay if you have many active users). To prevent this you should make a new function that handles new seconds and make some events for beginning of new second, instead of processing everything in a click handler.

```
struct ClicksTrackingInfo {
    uint32_t clicksCount;
    uint32_t clicksQuotaPerSec;
};

using UserId_t = int32_t; // user id type
std::set<UserId_t> activeUsers; // users who ever clicked in this second -- O(logN) to update

std::map<UserId_t, ClicksTrackingInfo> clicksPerCurrentSecond; // clicks counts -- O(logN) to update

uint64_t nextSecondTs; // holds nanosecond for beginning of the next second, e.g. if it's a 15th second then nextSecondTs == 16*1000*1000*1000

void onNewButtonPress(uint64_t& nanosecondsTimestamp, UserId_t userId)
{
    // first find out if a new second started
    if (nanosecondsTimestamp > nextSecondTs) {
        nextSecondTs = (nanosecondsTimestamp / 1000000000 + 1) * 1000000000; // leave only seconds part of next second
        // clear all records from active users of last second
        for (auto userId : activeUsers) {
             clicksPerCurrentSecond[userId].clicksCount = 0;   
        }
        activeUsers.clear(); // new second, no users yet
    }
    // now process current click by the user
    auto& [clicksCount, clicksLimit] = clicksPerCurrentSecond[userId]; // C++17 syntax
    ++clicksCount;
    if (clicksCount > clicksLimit) {
        report(userId);
        // return; // possibly deny this click
    }
    activeUsers.emplace(userId); // remember this user was active in current second
    // doClick(); // do the click action
}
```

Comment: You said earlier. "The advantage is simplicity, but disadvantage is that if user starts clicking in the end of a second, then he has say 1000 clicks for the remaining of this second plus 1000 clicks for the next second (i.e. he can do for example 2000 clicks per 1.1 second, but it only works for the first second, the next seconds will be limited properly)". If a user did his first click at the end of the second interval we can limit him still by getting the ratio of a second to the remaining time.

Comment: If we get a ratio we can then limit the user by multiplying that ratio by the max number of clicks per second. Say for example. He clicked when there was 0.2 seconds remaining till the second interval . Ratio betwen 1s and 0.2 is 5. So if a user was allowed to click 200 times per second, then he is only allowes to click 200 / 5 = 40 per 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your idea, anyways. I really like this way as well because of its simplicity. The only thing which I would like to avoid is extra memory for a set. of active users.

Comment: @slaventos I know the ratio could be a solution, but still not ideal (maybe you would want to allow user use all 1000 clicks in this 0.1 sec and then deny new clicks for 0.9 sec, while ratio allows only to use 100 clicks per 0.1 sec.

Comment: @slaventos and `set`'s memory usage is comparable to your map of `UserTrackingInfo`, it's also negligible unless you have **really** lots of simultaneous users